# How to POST multi-dimensional array to PHP

Tags: php, ios, arrays

I have an array of arrays of dictionaries. 
Example
MainArray
  SubArray1
     Dict 1
     Dict 2
  SubArray2
     Dict 1
     Dict 2

Here is the code before I send an NSMutableUrlRequest using the string output.

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:itemListArray
                                                   options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Which then goes to

```
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[urlRequest setHTTPBody:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

An NSUrlConnection follows.

The jsonstring output is
[[{"Description":"Item1"},{"Description":"Item2"}],[{"Description":"SItem1"},{"Description":"SItem2"}]]

My PHP code is pretty simple and returns the jsonstring as above.

```
$data1 = $_POST["jsonstring"];
var_dump($data1);
```

My issue now is I don't know how to separate the arrays. Do I have to set up some string formatting to separate the data? 
For example, pull all data between each set of brackets []. Then further separate data between all ""?

Is there an easier way to post a multi-dimensional array of dictionaries?

Comment: Use `json_decode()` function

Comment: the `$result = json_decode($data1);`? then var_dump it?

Comment: Works with the single quotes around the posted variable but it causes terminal to hang when they are not present. Is that right?

Comment: Yes. Because in your output json is like a string.

Comment: Note to anybody else viewing this: single quotes required with Curl but do not use in objective-c code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data1 = '[[{"Description":"Item1"},{"Description":"Item2"}],[{"Description":"SItem1"},{"Description":"SItem2"}]]';

var_dump(json_decode($data1, true));
```

or without the true as second parameter to allow objects instead of converting them to arrays

```
var_dump(json_decode($data1));
```

OUTPUT:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["Description"]=>
      string(5) "Item1"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(1) {
      ["Description"]=>
      string(5) "Item2"
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["Description"]=>
      string(6) "SItem1"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(1) {
      ["Description"]=>
      string(6) "SItem2"
    }
  }
}
```